# How to attach image on react page

Tags: reactjs, cucumber, capybara-webkit

How to upload(attach image)  the image on react pages using (capybara webkit+ cucumber) for integration UI testing.

I am able to attach an image to rails page but react pages i am unable to upload?

I tried some solutions, still unable to find solution.

1) `attach_file('.pb-text-field__browse_file_label', image_file_name)`

2) `find('.pb-text-field__browse_file_label').set('/scratch/data/1.png')`

Actual HTML:

```
<form>
  <div class="file text-field">
    <div class="text-field__input-wrapper">
      <div class="text-field__box"></div>
      <div class="text-field__upload_file">
        <input class="text-field__file-input" placeholder="Upload only jpeg or png images" disabled=""> 
        <div class="text-field__browse_file"> 
          <label class="text-field__browse_file_label" for="image-file">Browse</label> 
          <input id="image-file" class="text-field__browse" type="file">{this is invisible} 
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: please add more detail about you code

Comment: What is the actual HTML?

Answer (score 1):

`attach_file` takes the file inputs name, id, or associated label text - https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions#attach_file-instance_method - so passing it a CSS class selector is never going to work.  You don't show what your actual HTML is, but assuming you had a file input like

```
<input id="my_file_input" name="some_name" type="file"/>
```

then you could do either of

```
attach_file('my_file_input', path_to_file)
attach_file('some_name', path_to_file)
```

The other issue you may be running into is that the file input is often hidden to allow for consistent styling across browsers.  If that is the case for your app then you can use the `make_visible` option to tell Capybara to make the file input visible, attach the file, and then rehide the input.

```
attach_file('my_file_input', path_to_file, make_visible: true)
```

**UPDATE:** now that actual HTML has been provided and confirmed that the file input is actually input any of the following should work

```
attach_file('image-file', path_to_file, make_visible: true)
attach_file('Browser', path_to_file, make_visible: true)
find('.text-field__browse_file').attach_file(path_to_file, make_visible: true)
```

Comment: But in my code i am having only class field like this  <input id="my_file_input" name="some_name" type="file"/>

Comment: @vinaykumarreddy You just showed the exact same HTML I put in my answer, while claiming it's different -- add the real HTML to your question, along with a couple of level of surrounding elements for scoping purposes

Comment: Thomas walpole,   Actually i tried to use the code which u have given. 
I came to know that react will not support jquery where it is giving '$' is undefined error while executing.

I have tried to execute as below:
```
#Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false

page.driver.enable_logging

browse_element = page.find(:xpath, "//input[@id='i-modal-file']", visible: false).trigger('click')

script = (browse_element)

page.execute_script(script)


But no luck, am still unable to attach image for react page.

Comment: @vinaykumarreddy I have no clue what jQuery has to do with this since nothing I posted uses jQuery, and the rest of the code in your previous comment makes no sense. Would you please just do what has been asked, edit your question and add the actual HTML for the file input (and some of the surrounding HTML) so that we can see what you're actually dealing with. If you aren't willing to provide the actual HTML then delete the question and stop wasting everyones time. See - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: we are using react app application.Your solution is working fine on  Rails application,but in react pages it is failing.

Comment: now i am giving proper html<form>
<div class="file text-field">
<div class="text-field__input-wrapper">
<div class="text-field__box"></div>
<div class="text-field__upload_file">
<input class="text-field__file-input" placeholder="Upload only jpeg or png images" disabled="">
<div class="text-field__browse_file">
<label class="text-field__browse_file_label" for="image--file">Browse</label>
"<input id="image-file" class="text-field__browse" type="file">"  {this is invisible}
</div>
</div>

Comment: @vinaykumarreddy I edited your question for you and copied and formatted the HTML you provided (so it's actually readable), and have added an update to my answer based on that HTML.  If those don't work for you then provide which one(s) you tried and the exact full error message you get.  Note: I'm not sure why the `for` attribute for the label has 2 -s in it, but the id of the file input only has one - Those should match so I don't know whether it was a typo or what?

Comment: @Thamas Walpole, It was a typo mistake, both fields id =for ='image-file'  are same.I have tried to execute as below: 1)attach_file('image-file', "/scratch/boy.png") out put :Unable to find field "image-file" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)  2)attach_file('image-file',"/scratch/boy.png", make_visible: true)  out put : invalid keys :make_visible, should be one of :count, :minimum, :maximum, :between, :text, :visible, :exact, :match, :wait, :disabled (ArgumentError)

Comment: @Thamas Walpole ,3)#Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false page.driver.enable_logging browse_element = page.find(:xpath, "//input[@id='image-file']", visible: false).trigger('click') script = (browse_element) page.execute_script(script) output :Unable to find field "image-file" (Capybara::ElementNotFound) . I tried many ways still  unable to upload image on react page. I need some guidance from your side to overcome this issue?

Comment: @vinaykumarreddy Finally some useful info -  The fact that it's telling you `:make_visible` is not a valid key means you're using a version of Capybara < 2.12.0.  Version 2.12.0 was released 18 months ago, so who knows how old the version you're using is.  Update your Capybara to something newer (going to the latest 2.x version - 2.18.0 - will probably be the least work currently, although you will want to upgrade to 3.x at some point)

Comment: We are using these versions in our project capybara-webkit (1.15.0),capybara> 2.3, it is greater than 2.12.0 please let me know if there are any other ways to resolve.

Comment: @vinaykumarreddy How is 2.3 >  2.12??? Check the exact version of Capybara you are using (look in your Gemfile.lock) because if you get the `make_visible` is not a valid option then you are using <= 2.11 and need to update.